# Why is tracert not showing my public ip address?

Tags: networking, router, gateway, traceroute

Tracert does not show the IP of my WAN interface, not the gateway also. My public IP starts with 37 and it does not appear in tracert.

```
tracert www.google.com
1     3 ms     3 ms     2 ms  vodafone.station [192.168.1.1]                                                            
2    24 ms    17 ms    17 ms  192.168.51.10                                                                             
3    16 ms    17 ms    17 ms  192.168.51.9                                                                              
4    25 ms    21 ms    24 ms  10.177.21.201                                                                             
5    27 ms    27 ms    27 ms  185.210.48.42                                                                             
6    30 ms    28 ms    29 ms  185.210.48.43                                                                             
7    43 ms    37 ms    38 ms  83.224.40.225                                                                             
8    38 ms    38 ms    40 ms  185.210.48.3                                                                              
9    41 ms    39 ms    40 ms  209.85.254.219                                                                           
10    38 ms    37 ms    39 ms  172.253.79.31                                                                            
11    39 ms    38 ms    38 ms  mil07s08-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.206.68]
```

Answer (score 6):

Traceroute results correspond to whole routers, not their individual interfaces. Even though a router has multiple IP addresses on various interfaces, it will always produce only one trace reply.

When doing so, the router will usually send that reply using an address from whichever interface the original request arrived through – in this case the LAN interface.

(This means that running traceroute between the same two hosts in opposite directions will show different IP addresses for the same routers.)

Comment: If I use a VPN instead of normal ISP I can see public ip of the WAN interface of VPN router in the lines of traceroute, with the normal ISP not, so I can't understand

Comment: Then I'd be more curious why you _are_ seeing your own address with the VPN, because that's actually the *un*usual case and not what's in your main post. (There can be a few causes though – sometimes the inbound interface doesn't even have an IP address so the router chooses a different one, sometimes the router is configured to always use a 'loopback' address.)